# Can I invert my Mac screen colors without affecting an ext display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, video

I want to connect an external display to my MBPro running 10.11.2 for hosting karaoke.

I want to invert my Mac display without inverting the external display. I had planned to avoid video mirroring and drag the video window to the external display, but I'm told that won't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In Display Settings inside System Preferences different color schemes or filters can be applied to each display. Try applying a regular filter to the external display and invert colors filter on the main display. If you have any other questions feel free to ask!

Comment: Great.  Do you have any links to places that might offer guidance on filters to do such a thing?  That's a bit out of my wheelhouse.